# Merging two objects with a list of p1_name and p1_email as well as p2_name and p2_email and the second object order of these fields may be different

Tags: javascript, object, merge, duplicates

The setup: I have an object of 'Student' each of which stores parent info as keys to the student. These keys look like:

```
const s1 = {
  name: "student Name",
  p1_name: "Parent one name",
  p1_email: "ParentOne@email.com",
  p2_name: "Parent Two name",
  p2_email: "ParentTwo@email.com",
}
```

Then the student comes in with new info:

```
const s1_v2 = {
  name: "New Name"
  p1_name: "Parent one name",
  p1_email: "ParentOneNewEmail@email.com",
  p2_name: "Parent Two name",
  p2_email: "ParentTwoNewEmail@email.com",
}
```

I could easily merge these with `s = {...s1, ...s1_v2}` If the parents match up. However the order might have changed from `p1` and `p2`. Or I have no `p2` and my `p1` values are what my `p2` values are. Thus if I merge them simply as above I would end up with:

```
const s1 = {
  name: "student Name"
  p1_name: "Parent Two name",
  p1_email: "ParentTwo@email.com",
  p2_name: "Parent two name",
  p2_email: "ParentTwo@email.com",
}
```

Yes I know the data structure is poor, it's what I'm working with right now. Down the road I plan to move it to a relational association.

So the question becomes how can I check my fields to make sure i merge them correctly?

Comment: "*merge them correctly*" - what exactly **is** the correct way of merging them in all the cases you describes (swapping, not having value, etc)?

Answer (score 0):

> the order might have changed from p1 and p2

That is not a problem.

```js
const s1 = {
  name: "student Name",
  p1_name: "Parent one name",
  p1_email: "ParentOne@email.com",
  p2_name: "Parent Two name",
  p2_email: "ParentTwo@email.com",
}

const s1_v2 = {
  name: "New Name",
  p1_name: "Parent Two name",
  p1_email: "ParentTwoNewEmail@email.com",
  p2_name: "Parent one name",
  p2_email: "ParentOneNewEmail@email.com",
}

const s = {...s1, ...s1_v2}

console.log(s)
```

> I have no p2 *(in the new values... I assume)*

You would need to delete parent #2 then...

```js
const s1 = {
  name: "student Name",
  p1_name: "Parent one name",
  p1_email: "ParentOne@email.com",
  p2_name: "Parent Two name",
  p2_email: "ParentTwo@email.com",
}

const s1_v2 = {
  name: "New Name",
  p1_name: "Parent Two name",
  p1_email: "ParentTwoNewEmail@email.com",
}

const s = {...s1, ...s1_v2}

if(!("p2_name" in s1_v2)){
  delete s.p2_name
  delete s.p2_email
}

console.log(s)
```